# Log into a Powershell session over SSH, but keep SFTP working?

Tags: ssh, powershell

I have recently reinstalled my Raspberry in an effort to try to get something useful out of it, so far so good, including getting .NET 8 running nicely on it.

Since I have started to use Powershell, I thought I'd see if I could use it on the Raspberry, and sure enough, works nicely.

I could even change the shell so that when I log on using SSH, I get dropped into a Powershell session instead of bash. Nice.

However, I used FileZilla to transfer files to and from the Raspberry, and this no longer connets when Powershell is the shell.

I changed the shell using:

```
chsh -s /usr/bin/pwsh
```

After this, FileZilla simply says "Fatal: unable to initialise SFTP on server: could not connect.

Changing it back to bash with

```
chsh -s /usr/bin/bash
```

And FileZilla is once again able to connect.

Is there a way for me to keep what I want (being dropped into a Powershell session, that when I exit the session I also disconnect from the Pi), while keeping FileZilla/SFTP working?

Currently I switched back to bash, and just start powershell once logged in, but I'd like to skip that step.

Comment: Paulus's answer to this question (NOT the accepted answer) is potentially relevant: https://serverfault.com/questions/653342/ssh-login-works-but-sftp-login-doesnt/

Comment: If that is the issue then the accepted answer to the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250379/sftp-on-linux-server-gives-error-received-message-too-long should get it all working.

Comment: @JonathanGray Using the internal sftp subsystem worked wonders, thanks! I will close my question as a duplicate. Ah, can't close questions on this site, I've left a note for the moderators.